# Listen for Google Cast Session Events on iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-cast

I'm using the Google Cast SDK from iOS. I'm able to cast my application correctly, but I'm not able to get the [`<GCKSessionManagerListener>` Protocol](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/reference/ios/protocol_g_c_k_session_manager_listener-p) to work correctly. According to the GCKSessionManager documenation, I should just be able to bind the listener and define the callbacks I care about, but they don't seem to be called:

I initialize and bind the listener (on the main application thread):

```
GCKCastOptions *options =
    [[GCKCastOptions alloc] initWithReceiverApplicationID:@"ABCDEFGH"];
[GCKCastContext setSharedInstanceWithOptions:options];

GCKSessionManager *sessionManager =
    [GCKCastContext sharedInstance].sessionManager;
[sessionManager addListener:self];
```

Then I've defined (in the same file):

```
#pragma mark - GCKSessionManagerListener

- (void)sessionManager:(GCKSessionManager *)sessionManager
    didStartSession:(GCKSession *)session {
  RCTLogInfo(@"EVENT didStartSession");
}
```

I've also tried the didStartCastSession variant without any luck either.

In my header file, I include the interface too:

```
@interface MyGoogleCast : NSObject <RCTBridgeModule, GCKSessionManagerListener>
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Check if `GCKCastContext` is not nil. This is the only option left.

Comment: `GCKCastContext sharedInstance` raises an exception if it's nil.

Comment: Have you looked at the Cast iOS sample: https://github.com/googlecast/CastVideos-ios initWithReceiverApplicationID is done in the app delegate and session manager addListener is done in the view controller viewDidLoad.

Comment: Yep. I've tried moving the init to app delegate and moving the addListener to the last possible moment (in the view as I load the media). No change.

Comment: @Levi Did you get this to work? I have the exact same problem.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve a similar problem by postponing the `addListener` call until later in the app lifecycle.